# How can I allow a group of users to view only their uploaded documents and allow other users group to view all the uploaded documents?

Tags: permissions, file-upload, view, library

I have divided my users into two groups. One can upload files whereas others are normal users. I want the first group to only view their uploaded files whereas I want the second group to view all the uploaded documents list. How can I achieve it? Is it possible for the users who are added in both groups to view the documents as I have specified?
Is it possible to do it in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following article shown procedure for manage the permission in views
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433486/How-to-set-view-level-permissions-out-of-the-box-i

So do the following,
Create first view with  `Created=[Me]` filter,and assign  the view to one group
Create another view without any filter assign to another group

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view using filter `Created=[Me]`
2. In the document/list library settings, in the advanced settings section, select the options to create/read/edit items that were created by user

Hope this helps

Comment: I had already done that. What I want is that the other group users should be able to see all the uploaded documents and not just the document uploaded by them.

Comment: "In the document/list library settings, in the advanced settings section, select the options to create/read/edit items that were created by user": this is not an option for *document libraries*...

Comment: You are right Evariste

Answer (score 0):

Is this about getting a default view for your users, or about security?
In the latter case, you have different options:

1. Set item-level security. However, this is not supported for doc libs (as opposite to simple lists). So, at your own risks... http://www.hersheytech.com/Blog/SharePoint/tabid/197/entryid/28/Default.aspx
2. For every user who can upload, create a specific folder with permissions for them to upload. The second group have read permissions on all folders.
3. Custom code, with an ER to set permissions or move files to a given folder (depending on the amount of files)

Comment: It is about view

Comment: It is about view. I am asking if it is possible to create a view for one  group of users and another view for other group of users ? I don't want a single view to be displayed for all the groups

Comment: OK, then, how about adding two List View Web parts on the home page, with 2 different views set on them? One with the view described by @chandra-shekhar, and the other one showing all documents?

Comment: How many users are involved there? Users from first group may create a personnal view, with the view described by @chandra-shekhar, and set it as their default view.

Comment: And another option, more a hack: add a Script Editor Web part on the list view page. It would contain JavaScript code using the SharePoint OM. That code would detect and redirect users from first group to another view URL...

Comment: But in that case both the views would be visible. I want only one view to be visible at a time.

Comment: OK, and what about the 2 other approaches I suggested? How many users are involved?